# How do I find latency, bandwidth and throughput between two nodes in a network?

Tags: networking, p2p

If I have a bunch of nodes connected via internet across the world, how do I find out latency, bandwidth and throughput between each nodes? Is there a central database that might have this information? e.g. ISPs or RIRs?

Comment: Those values can change at any time on the public Internet.

Comment: No, there is no such database, and it wouldn't do you much good if it existed, since the *available* bandwidth and latency depends on utilisation. You can try to measure them; that's about all.

Answer (score 1):

You benchmark. if you have control over all of those nodes you could benchmark the time it takes to send messages between them. this kinds of benchmark can be as simple as message exchange between 2 nodes and more complicated like spreading a message while the network is under heavy [chrun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Churn_rate).